# Uncaught TypeError: state.productDetails is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, dispatch

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails, clearErrors } from "../../actions/productActions";


const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();

  const { loading, error, product } = useSelector((state) =>
    state.productDetails()

  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails());
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, alert, error]);
  return (
    <>
      {!loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className='row f-flex justify-content-around'>
            <div className='col-12 col-lg-5 img-fluid' id='product_image'>
              <img
                src='https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/1223a935-2a61-480a-95a1-21904ff8986c_1.17fa3d7870e3d9b1248da7b1144787f5.jpeg?odnWidth=undefined&odnHeight=undefined&odnBg=ffffff'
                alt='sdf'
                height='500'
                width='500'/>
            </div>
            <div className='col-12 col-lg-5 mt-5'>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
              <p id='product_id'>Product # sklfjdk35fsdf5090</p>
              <hr />
              <div className='rating-outer'>
                <div className='rating-inner'></div>
              </div>
              <span id='no_of_reviews'>(5 Reviews)</span>
              <hr />
              <p id='product_price'>$108.00</p>
              <div className='stockCounter d-inline'>
                <span className='btn btn-danger minus'>-</span>
                <input
                  type='number'
                  className='form-control count d-inline'
                  value='1'
                  readOnly
                />
                <span className='btn btn-primary plus'>+</span>
              </div>
              <button
                type='button'
                id='cart_btn'
                className='btn btn-primary d-inline ml-4'
              >
                Add to Cart
              </button>
              <hr />
              <p>
                Status: <span id='stock_status'>In Stock</span>
              </p>
              <hr />
              <h4 className='mt-2'>Description:</h4>
              <p>
                Binge on movies and TV episodes, news, sports, music and more!
                We insisted on 720p High Definition for this 32" LED TV,
                bringing out more lifelike color, texture and detail. We also
                partnered with Roku to bring you the best possible content with
                thousands of channels to choose from, conveniently presented
                through your own custom home screen.
              </p>
              <hr />
              <p id='product_seller mb-3'>
                Sold by: <strong>Amazon</strong>
              </p>
              <button
                id='review_btn'
                type='button'
                className='btn btn-primary mt-4'
                data-toggle='modal'
                data-target='#ratingModal'
              >
                Submit Your Review
              </button>
              <div className='row mt-2 mb-5'>
                <div className='rating w-50'>
                  <div
                    className='modal fade'
                    id='ratingModal'
                    tabIndex='-1'
                    role='dialog'
                    aria-labelledby='ratingModalLabel'
                    aria-hidden='true'
                  >
                    <div className='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                      <div className='modal-content'>
                        <div className='modal-header'>
                          <h5 className='modal-title' id='ratingModalLabel'>
                            Submit Review
                          </h5>
                          <button
                            type='button'
                            className='close'
                            data-dismiss='modal'
                            aria-label='Close'
                          >
                            <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='modal-body'>
                          <ul className='stars'>
                            <li className='star'>
                              <i className='fa fa-star'></i>
                            </li>
                            <li className='star'>
                              <i className='fa fa-star'></i>
                            </li>
                            <li className='star'>
                              <i className='fa fa-star'></i>
                            </li>
                            <li className='star'>
                              <i className='fa fa-star'></i>
                            </li>
                            <li className='star'>
                              <i className='fa fa-star'></i>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                          <textarea
                            name='review'
                            id='review'
                            className='form-control mt-3'
                          ></textarea>
                          <button
                            className='btn my-3 float-right review-btn px-4 text-white'
                            data-dismiss='modal'
                            aria-label='Close'
                          >
                            Submit
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests

> state.productDetails is not a function

This is because productDetails is a reducer object and Not a function created by redux. Hence, your code should be

```
const { loading, error, product } = useSelector((state) =>state.productDetails); //Note: productDetails without '()'
```

Hope it helps.

Side Note: While posting any question or answer please format the code properly next time so it's readable. :)

Comment: thank you very much. side note noted. but please  i did and this is the error am now getting from console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')